You are too… that you… vs you are too… so that vs you are too… to
I have a somewhat heated discussion with an acquaintance about the following meme and its grammar:

YOU ARE TOO INVESTED IN how u are perceived that u cannot fully enjoy
living!

He claims that it is wrong and instead should be „you are so invested that... or you are too invested to...“ while I think that the meme is grammatically correct.
Who is in the right?

Your friend is right - You are so invested in how you are perceived that you cannot fully enjoy living, OR You are too invested in how you are perceived to fully enjoy living.

@MichaelHarvey has it, though your sentence would pass in conversation.

@YosefBaskin: It would only "pass in conversation" if you thought the person saying it wasn't a native Anglophone. If they were, I think most other native Anglophones would think it was most peculiar. It's unquestionably an "error", and imho not the kind the natives would normally either commit or let pass unremarked.

... He is too drunk that he can't drive. I don't think so.

@FumbleFingers, you are right. I was knot.

@YosefBaskin: I think the mere fact that initially it didn't bother you much implies it's a very useful question for learners! I was remiss in not upvoting the question immediately, but I've certainly done that now! (All we need now is an answer beefing up Michael's comment! :)

We commonly use the construction so (verb) that (some condition is true or false).
There's no parallel construction for the word too. You'd have to change the sentence a bit, like in Michael's comment. Italics show the parts changed.

You are too invested in how you are perceived to fully enjoy living

Or

You are too invested in how you are perceived! How on earth are you supposed to fully enjoy living?

That said, the meme as written would, I believe, be understood by most native or near-native English speakers, at least in the West. Remember that native speakers make all sorts of grammar errors. Also, this is Internet speech, where adherence to proper grammar and sometimes spelling is typically lower than more formal settings.
